# Scrape Data on chart Python

Tags: python, web-scraping

Do you know how can I **scrape** the values on the chart data on this page in python?
Is it possible or not feasible?

```
https://platform.napbots.com/strategyDetails/STRAT_BTC_USD_D_2_V2

import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
import re


url = 'https://platform.napbots.com/strategyDetails/STRAT_BTC_USD_D_2_V2'
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: What data do you need from that page?

Comment: The values on the chart

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you see in chart is loaded from external URL. You can use this example how to load it:

```
import json
import requests


url = "https://middle.napbots.com/v1/strategy/details/STRAT_BTC_USD_D_2_V2"
data = requests.get(url).json()

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

for d in data["data"]["performance"]["quotes"]["NapoX BTC AR daily"]:
    print(d["date"], d["last"])
```

Prints:

```
...
2021-03-24 8090496.4614
2021-03-25 8090496.4614
2021-03-26 8090496.4614
2021-03-27 7971715.2932
2021-03-28 7959911.2069
2021-03-29 8223204.2625
```

Comment: Thank you, amazing, how can I find the external url by myself on the other strategies?

Comment: @Ricdm Look at Firefox developer tools->Network tab (or something similar in Chrome). There are all requests that the page is doing - including to external urls